# Compute $E[N_t N_s]$ function of Poisson Process

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

> Let $N_t$ be a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$. Compute the
>   function:
>
> $$c(s,t) = E[N_t N_s]$$

My attempt:

Write:
$E[N_t N_s] = E[E[N_t N_s|N_s]]=E[N_s E[N_t|N_s]]=E[N_sE[N_{|t-s|}]]=E[N_s]E[N_{|t-s|}] = (s\lambda) * (|t-s| \lambda) = \lambda^2s|t-s|$

I have a feeling I have a mistake due to lack of symmetry between $s$ and $t$ in the final result. Am I making any mistakes in the computation?

Comment: For any process with independent increment, for $s\le t$ we have $$cov(N_s,N_t)=cov(N_s,N_s+(N_t-N_s))=cov(N_s,N_s)=var(N_{s\wedge t})$$ In case of $Poisson(\lambda)$, we get $cov(N_s,N_t)=\lambda(s\wedge t)$.

Comment: Your error is in the third equality. It should be (assuming $s<t$): $\mathsf E(N_s\,\mathsf E(N_t\mid N_s)) = \mathsf E(N_s \,\mathsf E(N_{t-s}+N_s\mid N_s))$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $t<s$, thinking in terms of disjoint blocks of time gives
\begin{align*}
E[N_t N_s]&= E[N_t\{N_s-N_t+N_t\}]\\
&=E[N_t]E[N_s-N_t]+E[N_t^2]\\
&=\lambda t(s-t)\lambda+\text{Var}[N_t]+E^2[N_t]\\
&=\lambda t(s-t)\lambda+\lambda t+(\lambda t)^2.
\end{align*}

Comment: ...which simplifies to $\lambda^2ts+\lambda t$, or in general $\lambda^2ts+\lambda \min(s,t)$